# Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/app

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, dependency-management, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to compile my project in Android Studio and I get the following error

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v13/app/FragmentCompat$FragmentCompatImpl;
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:594)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:552)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:533)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:170)
      at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:439)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:287)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:230)
      at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:199)
      at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:103)
```

Running

```
$ gradle -q dependencies
```

Yields the following results

```
compile - Classpath for compiling the main sources.
+--- project :facebookSDK
+--- project :stripe
+--- project :paymentKitLibrary
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+ -> 19.1.0
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0
+--- com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4
\--- com.android.support:support-v13:+ -> 19.1.0
     \--- com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0
```

Here are my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':facebookSDK')
    compile project(':stripe')
    compile project(':paymentKitLibrary')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.23'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'){
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:+"
    compile files('libs/crashlytics.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsV2.jar')
    compile files('libs/MobileAppTracker.jar')
    compile files('libs/twitter4j-core-3.0.5.jar')
}
```

I do not understand where the conflict is coming from. Is it possible it is coming from one of the jar files ? What is the problem anyway ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the class "android.support.v13.app.FragmentCompat$FragmentCompatImpl" is declared twice in the dependencies.  This class is included in both of the following dependencies:

```
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

compile "com.android.support:support-v13:+"
```

The "support-v13" library already contains the "appcompat-v7" library.

Try removing the "appcompat-v7" library from your "build.gradle" file and it should compile.

```
// *** remove this ****
compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I tried, but if I remove it throws all kind of compilation errors in `themes.xml` for example `<style name="myApp.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">` gives `cannot resolve symbol`

Comment: "The "support-v13" library already contains the "appcompat-v7" library." -- no, it does not. `support-v13` contains the contents of `support-v4`, not `appcompat-v7`.